# Can I add dropbox links to my resume for graduate school applications?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, website

I am applying for Masters in ECE, since setting up a personal website at short notice is impossible,I wanted to provide dropbox links in my CV. For example:

1. Worst Outgoing Student Award         [Certificate]
2. Bachelors in Bunking Classes         [Relevant Coursework]
3. Book Report on Taming of the Shrew   [Report]

All the [**] fields are basically dropbox links, accessible to all. I wanted to know if this is recommended or not.

Comment: Is the website a requirement? If it isn't skip the DropBox. That's tacky in a CV, which should be considered a paper document, so no hyperlinks to long URLs.

Comment: @Compass If the issue is length of URL, there are plenty of URL shorteners out there. Dropbox even has its own.

Comment: Related: [Is it advisable to have many clickable hyperlinks in an academic CV?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21436/is-it-advisable-to-have-many-clickable-hyperlinks-in-an-academic-cv)

Comment: The website is highly recommended, especially in case you have a lot of projects to brag about.I am not one such person!!  The issue is not about length of the URL(latex typesetting), it is about whether the Admissions Committee would be interested in being fed with additional relevant information. For example, the certificate link in Point 1 would make my case more authentic. Another example, if I have done coursework in Physics, how will the Committee know whether I referred the books by Irodov or Halliday or Feynman? The {Relevant Coursework} link helps in this case.

Comment: _setting up a personal website by the deadline tomorrow is impossible_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @ff524: The question to which you refer seems to apply to the CV of an academic, *i.e.* a faculty member.  The current question is about the CV that's part of an application for admission.  I believe those are used in very different ways, and that the application CV should stand completely on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Your CV should stand on its own.  Admissions committees are likely to have stacks of material through which to look, and will almost certainly make a decision based on what you send them.  It is most *unlikely* that they'll be willing to hunt around to find things you should have told them directly, and even *less* likely if they have to download documents from Dropbox instead of just displaying them.

Spend your time making your CV as good as you can instead of spending time trying to take shortcuts, because that's what those Dropbox links will look like to the committee.

Comment: I agree with your view of avoiding Dropbox links.I felt that since my college and internships have been completed at relatively unknown places in India, I atleast wanted to add hyperlinks to the official websites of such places(just to help them save time in Copy-Search-Go) . Also, please let me know if I can add links to code in my github repository, since it would help professors judge my understanding of some term projects.

Comment: Can someone please look into this? It is kind of urgent.

Comment: @AgrimRaghav:  Well, I answered your question.  If you are now wishing for an answer that validates what you apparently want to do, you're going to have to wait for someone who disagrees with me.